# What are the sign twirlers and street performers for?

Tags: infamous-second-son

Is there any purpose to the sign twirling and street performing people in the city? They get their own markers on the map so the game is singling them out for some purpose. I have read something on a loading screen that starts off talking about them but I can not finish reading it to see if there is something useful about these people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are there for evil karma purposes, same with the protesters. Killing them or stopping their performance acquires some evil karma and eventually a trophy after doing it enough times. This is similar to beating the drug dealers for good karma. Additionally there are people laying on the street or sides of the street who need "help" and will ask for it. With these people you can "help" them by healing them and receiving good karma in return, or execute them and receive bad karma in return. What you want to do depends on how you plan on playing it, good or bad.

Comment: Are these the opposites of the people who need help then?

Comment: The people who need help can go either way. You can either "help" them by healing for good karma or execute them for bad karma. I'll update my answer with that too I guess.

Comment: How is killing them any different than just killing any of the people out and around?

Comment: They give extra bad karma. You don't even have to kill them in most cases just use a power on them and it will pop up with an alert, like when you kill drug dealers. They are like side objectives basically, just there to make leveling up or down your karma easier and faster. You also get a trophy for killing or stopping 10 of them, I believe it is that many anyway.